# marketing hypothesis test sample size calculation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, gamma-distribution, marketing

I am trying to design a coupon promotion test to measure the increase in the volume of orders from promotion versus no promotion. To do so, I want to calculate the pre-group sample size required to get a significant read on the difference in the orders placed between those two groups.

- The population is a segment of our customers which haves a high risk of churn and high value.
- The redemption rate for this kind of retention coupon is about 4%.
- H0: the number of orders placed by the treatment group in a month after the program = the number of orders placed by the control group in a month after the program
- H1: the number of orders placed by the treatment group in a month after the program > the number of orders placed by the control group in a month after the program
- In the end of the month, I will calculate the total number of orders of the treatment and control group. The experiment would be easy to design if the number of orders placed follows normal distribution, but the number of orders a group of customers place in a month should follows gamma distribution. How would I calculate the sample size if the thing that I want to compare follows gamma distribution?